# Error LNK 2005 & LNK1169 C++ Visual Studio DLL

Tags: c++, class, visual-studio-2013, dll, lnk2005

I'm trying to create a DLL plugin for OBS, but when I try to compile a simple script it gives me the following errors -

```
Error   1   error LNK2005: _DllMain@12 already defined in dllmain.obj   c:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\name\nameEnhanced\nameEnhanced.obj  nameEnhanced
```

and

```
Error   2   error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found   c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\name\Debug\nameEnhanced.dll 1   1   nameEnhanced
```

I've created a simple script, which only has 2 files namely -

```
handle.h
nameEnhanced.cpp
```

these are my files -

handle.h

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

namespace MsgeBox
{
    class myMessage
    {
    public:
        static void createMessage(HWND windowsOwner, LPCWSTR theMessage, LPCWSTR theTitle, UINT theIcon){
            MessageBox(windowsOwner, theMessage, theTitle, theIcon);
        }
    };
}
```

and

nameEnhanced.cpp

```
 // nameEnhanced.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
    //

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include "handle.h"

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    MsgeBox::myMessage::createMessage(NULL, (LPCWSTR)"Hello", (LPCWSTR)"I See You.", MB_ICONWARNING | MB_CANCELTRYCONTINUE);
    switch (fdwReason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        // attach to process
        // return FALSE to fail DLL load
        break;

    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        // detach from process
        break;

    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        // attach to thread
        break;

    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        // detach from thread
        break;
    }
    return TRUE; // successful
}
```

I've tried to delete the `dllmain.obj` file but that didn't work

I've used https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx as a base for my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Visual Studio provides a `dllmain.cpp` source file with the DLL project template and you say:

> I've tried to delete the dllmain.obj file but that didn't work

However that won't stop it being recreated every build.  You need to clean the project and then delete `dllmain.cpp` from the project.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with using Visual Studio.

Comment: alright, that worked, I never asked you to tell me how to remove a file, I just thought that you meant something else, no need to attack people.